# hard code exact float values in python

Tags: python, numpy, precision

This is probably overkill for my problem, but I am curious about the answer.

I have a matrix of `np.float32` values that I want to put into some code.  It's 50x3 so I want to just put it in the source directly - it's not something that will change often.  It's a little sensitive to rounding, so I want to encode the data *exactly* if possible.  Is there a good way to do this in the source while also preserving the matrix format?

I'm thinking something along the lines of putting [[0xC45B36F3, ...],...] and somehow encoding that to a `np.float32`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you chose to encode the integer values, you could then do:

```
int_data = np.array([[0xC45B36F3, ...],...], dtype=np.uint32)
floats = int_data.view(np.float32)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the [`numpy.save`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html#numpy.save) builtin? I've tried it with several float32 inputs and the [`numpy.load`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load) had no rounding issues.

Or is there any reason why you can't or don't want to do it that way?

Comment: Each row is associated to a separate set of data, so I wanted to have a matrix in the source so it would be easy to see changes per dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the matrix `m` in bytes :

```
m.tobytes()
```

Then you paste the bytes it in your code :

```
data=b'\x34f\xd3.......paste the 4*50*3 bytes here ......\x12'
```

After you can reconstruct the exact matrix :

```
m=matrix(frombuffer(data,float32).reshape(50,3))
```

without any loss.